# Calculating length of a string according to modbus in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hex, decimal, modbus

I am working on `modbus` communication. I am trying to get the length of a frame which is in actual a string.

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(reader["read_param"].ToString());
            }
var single = string.Join("",data);
```

The resultant string is

```
4A601933906620468040204220442040004200404020602260246
```

As per documentation, the length is `1B` in `hex` and `27` in `decimal`

But when I try to get the length `int length = combine.Length;` I am getting `53`. How to get it in `HEX`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation. You mention that you are getting 53 and you want to get it in HEX. You can do  string HEX = length.ToString("X"); Please try to elaborate your question further. The problem is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting byte to string which converts each single byte to 1 or 2 string characters. So the 53 you are getting from `combine.Length` is the length of the converted string, the `0x1B` from modbus protocol is the length of the byte string. You are getting 53 string characters instead of 54 because one of the bytes was probably a 0x0X so the leading zero is stripped off.

I am unsure of which reader you are using, but if it reads in byte, you can add a counter to determine the length of the modbus message.

Answer (score 0):

When a string is sent, the encoded string is sent in some standard format, the most popular is UTF-8 with which each character can occupy from 1 to 4 bytes.

So the encoded string can have more bytes than characters in the string.